# When do I need to submit my app for Facebook review (when only reduced group of people will use it)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, user-roles

I am creating an app that only a specific list of users will use, and I need  Instagram Public Content Access permission (and some other permissions) for them (I have my Instagram Business Account all set up and connected with Facebook page).

On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/examples/#screencast there is stated:

> You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or
>   by a reduced number of people. Any account listed in the Roles tab in
>   your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can access
>   all permissions and generate a user or page access token.

So I just want to make sure, that it is completely fine in my case to keep my app in development mode and let my users use it like this (so I don't need to submit my app for review as long as all the users are going to have their role assigned in my app), and that these permissions are not intended just for a limited time period or only for testing/development purposes.

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you quoted there, is applicable to *permissions* your app is going to ask its users to grant to it.

Instagram Public Content Access is not a permission, it is a *feature*. You need to get it reviewed, if you want your app to be able to access content that the users of your app do not have admin access to.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-INSTAGRAM_PUBLIC_CONTENT_ACCESS